# What was the reason of the non-preemptivity of older Linux kernels?

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, scheduling, preemption

Why did the first Linux developers choose to implement a non-preemptive kernel? Is it to save synchronization?

As far as I know, Linux was developed in the early 90's, when PCs had a single processor. What advantage does a non-preemptive kernel give in such PCs? Why, however, the advantage is reduced by multi-core processors?

Comment: We also have a [Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site as well, which may be of help.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for design theory discussions, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Linux was intended to be somewhat compatible with the versions of Unix already out there, notably System V and BSD.

Unix of that era was very primitive compared to the commercial operating systems available at that time and in many ways remains so to this day. The big selling point of Unix in the 1990 was "open systems." Unix allowed the various upstart computer companies (e.g., Apollo, Sun) to have an operating system without doing much operating system development. They were able to turn the really poor quality of Unix compared to commercial operating systems of the day (e.g. VMS) into an advantage as an "open system."

One of the many features lacking in Unix was a preemptive kernel. If you are building a Unix clone, there was little reason to create one.

There are DEC and IBM systems that run for years without rebooting. It's amazing how far backwards we have gone.